# How to create a Event in Django-Scheduler while creating a Object in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-scheduler

I am a total newbie in Python and new on StackOverFlow. If I am missing something please let me know

This is Django-scheduler App:- https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler

It giver various options to create events and occurrences

Documentation is here:- http://django-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have a model known as Product in Django. Which is defined as below

```
`class Products(models.Model):
 product_choice = (
    ('1' ,'sightseeing'),
    ('2','daytour'),
    ('3','activity'),
    ('3','experience'),
    ('4','rentals'),
    ('3','multidaytrip'),
)

 product_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=product_choice, null=True) 
 category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

 pic1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='media/ross-island-2.jpg')
 pic2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='media/ross-island-2.jpg')
 pic3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='media/ross-island-2.jpg')


 shared_code = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
 age_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
 time_slots = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,blank=True, default='')
 location = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,blank=True, default='')
 duration = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,blank=True, default='')

 affiliated_institutions = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
 includes = models.TextField(blank=True)
 excludes = models.TextField(blank=True)
 medical_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
 perks_included =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
 product_detail = models.TextField()
 vender_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
 user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
 vendor_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
 about_vender = models.TextField()
 price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 child_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 infant_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 product_detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
 slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
 total_slots = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 open_slots = models.IntegerField(blank=True , null=True)


 cancellation_policy = models.TextField(blank=True)


  def __unicode__(self):  
return str(self.title)

 def __str__(self):
return str(self.title)
```

`

I have installed the Django-Scheduler in my Django Application, however it is installed as a separate app. 
I am using Django Rest Framework(DRF) and doing all these alterations via DRF.

```
class ProductListAPIView(ListAPIView):


 queryset = Products.objects.all()
 permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )
 serializer_class = ProductSerializer
 def get_queryset(self):
 return Products.objects.all()


 def get(self, request, format=None):
    snippets = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer_class.data)





 def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`

Now I need to create events with the help of Django-Scheduler while creating the Product when a new request comes via Django Rest Framework.

Thanks in anticipation, Please let me know if I am missing on any part.